# NodeJS in production

Tags: node.js

I have to ask you guys a question. I just started looking at NodeJS for a project with some friends of mine. Now we have reached the point in our planning that we have started to think about how a NodeJS solution is deployed in production. Do we need a web server for this (IIS or Apache)? My initial thought is "no" since this will force to declare ports twice, once in the web server and once in the NodeJS code. Or should NodeJS just be run as "node server.js"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run NodeJS you just `node server.js` but there are a few better extensions that handle that. So, you can run node in windows, but I highly recommend UNIX platforms through SSH access to your server (most of VPS have this). If you cannot afford such type of server, I'd go with [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/), [Dotcloud](https://www.dotcloud.com/) or [Nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com/) (the three of them are cloud hosting).

- [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) which restarts your node server when it crashes
- [Nodemon](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/12/nodejs-rapid-development-nodemon/) which restarts your node server when the file has been modified (or any JS files in a specified directory)

There might be more, so if I find anything useful, I'll edit this post.

Comment: Actually, we have almost decided that we will use dotCloud since it has reasonable pricing. But now you put a new variable in my calculations, Forever or Nodemon, our PaaS provider must have some kind of recovery feature like that. But at least we don't have to run everything on a web server then. Thanks.

Comment: Also for local development I recommend using http://yeoman.io/ :D it's so awesome!